# How to give color to blurrview in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiblureffect

I have created a blur view and added in the subview of main view. This is my code:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.tintColor  = UIColor.green
blurEffectView.tag = 999;
let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: self.internalView.frame.size.width + self.internalView.frame.origin.x, y: self.drawerView.frame.origin.y, width: self.drawerView.frame.size.width - self.internalView.frame.size.width, height: self.drawerView.frame.size.height)

blurEffectView.frame = frame
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.drawerView.insertSubview(blurEffectView, belowSubview: self.btnClose)
```

Now, I want to make it as dark green blur.

[image]

How can I achieve this using the code above?

Comment: Check this tut - > https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial

Answer (score 6):

Try this: Swift 3.0

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: UIBlurEffect.init(style: .light))
    visualEffectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
    visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(visualEffectView)

}
```

This line of code should change the background color of `visualEffectView`.

```
visualEffectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Change the alpha value to 0.5

Comment: @dhiraj I have updated my answer! Try this and let me know if it's works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one and adjust the alpha value:

```
blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```